# Удаление insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const modal = document.createElement('div')
function createModal (src){
    modal.classList.add('modalBg');
    modal.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 
        `<div class="modalWr">
            <div id="close-modal" onclick="closeModal()">
                <p class="closeModalX">X</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modalImgBlock">
                <img src="${src}" alt="" id="imgModal">
                <div class="modalBlockControl">
                    <button>btn1</button> <button>btn2</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    )
    document.body.append(modal);
}
```

Создал таким образом "модальное окно", а когда пытаюсь закрыть и открыть с другим изображением эти два блока перекрывают друг-друга. Каким образом можно полностью удалить окно? Использую remove().

Comment: Заменить insertAdjacentHTML на innerHTML ?

Comment: не думаю, что это решение))

Comment: Ну вместо создания / удаления новых окон, можно создать всего одно, и при необходимости только менять его содержимое (или даже не содержимое, а просто src картинки)... и показывать/скрывать через display: block / none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createModal (src){
    const modal = document.createElement('div')
    modal.classList.add('modalBg');
    modal.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 
        `<div class="modalWr">
            <div id="close-modal" onclick="closeModal()">
                <p class="closeModalX">X</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modalImgBlock">
                <img src="${src}" alt="" id="imgModal">
                <div class="modalBlockControl">
                    <button>btn1</button> <button>btn2</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
    )

document.body.append(modal);
}
```

Нужно просто вызывать метод removeChild()
Пример: 
`function closeModal() {
            modal.removeChild(document.querySelector('.modalWr'));
            modal.remove();
}`

Answer (score 2):

А если вот так?

```
const modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.classList.add('modalBg');
modal.innerHTML = `
  <div class="modalWr">
    <div id="close-modal" onclick="closeModal()">
      <p class="closeModalX">X</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modalImgBlock">
      <img src="" alt="" id="imgModal">
      <div class="modalBlockControl">
        <button>btn1</button> <button>btn2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

function showModal (src){
  document.getElementById("imgModal").src = src;
  modal.classList.add('modal-show');
}

function closeModal (){
  modal.classList.remove('modal-show');
}
```